# Problem to convert to a FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api

I want in Python make a script that:

1. Import the local shape file "D:/Municipios.shp",
2. With Google Earth Engine API import the band 'Tair_f_inst' of the collection 'NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H', between 2023-01-01 and 2023-12-31,
3. I want to instead of trying to calculate the mean for each feature individually with Earth Engine, I want to aggregate data locally on my machine,
4. In my local machine for each value of the feautre "DANE" of the shapefile and for each month of the time range (ie. between 2023-01-01 and 2023-12-31), calculate the mean value of band 'Tair_f_inst' and
5. Save the result in a table with the next columns: "DANE", "Month", "Value".

However, I get this error message:

> EEException: Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection: 0       ee.Geometry({\n  "functionInvocationValue": {...
> 1       ee.Geometry({\n  "functionInvocationValue": {...

Here is my code:

```py
import geemap
import geopandas as gpd
import ee
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape

ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

shapefile_path = "D:/Municipios.shp"
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: mapping(x))


#HERE IS THE ERROR

feature_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(gdf['geometry'].apply(ee.Geometry))


start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2023-12-31'

image_collection = (ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
                    .select(['Tair_f_inst'])
                    .filterDate(ee.Date(start_date), ee.Date(end_date)))

def calculate_mean(feature):
    feature = ee.Feature(feature)
    mean_value = image_collection.reduceRegion(
        reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
        geometry=feature.geometry(),
        scale=25000,
        maxPixels=1e13
    )
    return feature.set(mean_value)

results = feature_collection.map(calculate_mean)


result_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(results.getInfo()['features'])

result_gdf['DANE'] = gdf['DANE']
result_gdf['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(result_gdf['properties.system:time_start']).dt.month
result_gdf['Value'] = result_gdf['properties.Tair_f_inst']


result_csv_path = "D:/result.csv"
result_gdf[['DANE', 'Month', 'Value']].to_csv(result_csv_path, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Earthengine feature collections accepts **geo_interface** dictionnaries as parameter so you can simply use:

```py
shapefile_path = "D:/Municipios.shp"
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
feature_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(gdf.__geo_interface__)
```

to know more about the geo_interface please refer to the [geopandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.__geo_interface__.html)